# iPad App adds margin when opened in landscape left, not in landscape right

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm experiencing a very odd layout bug with a landscape iPad app.

The application launches and runs perfectly when it is started in landscape-right orientation. However, when started in landscape-left, there is a 20px margin added to the top of the main view.

The design of this app has a title bar at the top and a navigation bar at the bottom (both are just UIViews with a couple of UILabels/UIButtons). When you start the app in the buggy landscape-left mode and switch to landscape-right, the top and bottom bars then move 20px *above* where they're supposed to be positioned – i.e. the top bar is positioned under the status bar, and the bottom bar is floating 20px above the bottom of the frame.

It's really very weird indeed. As I said, it works *perfectly* if you open it in landscape-right.

Anyone got any thoughts? Seen this bug?

I'm using iOS SDK 6.1 and Xcode 4.6

**Edit [more details]**

Some possible clues from some logs I added – the main view has a frame of (0,0,1024,748), while a call to [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] returns a frame of (20,0,748,1024), which is portrait. Certainly curious, but doesn't necessarily explain the inconsistency between launch states – the logs are identical between the error state and the functional mode.

**Edit [the plot thickens]**

So I've checked all the view frames, and have created a reproduceable error.

There is a fullscreen 'slideshow' mode within the app, in which the status bar is hidden. I am able to rotate the 20px gap-error when the application is rotated in this fullscreen mode.

So the process is:

-App working normally, rotating fine
-Enter fullscreen show, appears okay
-Rotate in fullscreen, layout shifts 20px
-Close slideshow, layout remains shifted
-Upon first rotation, the layout returns to normal

Getting there… is there something akin to setWantsFullScreenLayout which I need to call here?

Answer (score 0):

20 pixels is the height of the status bar, an offset of 20px in relation to rotation almost always has something to do with the frame of your (root) view controller. Try setting your root view controller's view frame to have a `0,0` origin.

Comment: That's was my first thought – there are fullscreen sections of the app, in which the status bar is hidden, however I removed all status bar-related business from the code, and from the info.plist.

Some possible clues from some logs I added – the main view has a frame of (0,0,1024,748), while a call to [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] returns a frame of (20,0,748,1024), which is portrait.

Certainly curious, but doesn't necessarily explain the inconsistency between launch states – the logs are identical between the error state and the functional mode.

Comment: I haven't re-checked recently, but iOS apps always launch in portrait mode, and if the device is rotated immediately get sent the rotation notifications. So you will always get the frame you found on an iPad during launch. Did you try changing the frame origin and autoresizing masks?